# Interviewer rescheduled final around one day prior for estimated date 2 months later

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, tech-industry

I've gone through 4 rounds of interviews for a management position with a well-known company and was supposed to have the final interview round tomorrow, but they've just rung to say the interviewers had some urgent meetings before flying back to HQ. The company would contact me again for interview dates in April when the interviewers fly back then.

Is this normal? Is it possible they've hired someone else?

Comment: Is it normal for someone to have to reschedule because of urgent meetings?  No.  But it is hardly unprecedented.  Is it possible that they've hired someone else?  Sure.  But it's unlikely-- companies planning on 5 rounds of interviews probably aren't trying to streamline the process by not interviewing everyone one last time.  Given that you're presumably still interviewing elsewhere, though, why does it matter?  If you have another offer before April, you can certainly let the company know that and see if they can do anything for you.

Answer (score 3):

They might have hired someone else, but why would a company come up with what would be a very lame excuse, instead of telling you? It's very unlikely.

Now your problem is: 1. Even in the best case, you will get that job two months later. 2. Two months is a long time, and anything can happen in two months, including the need for an employee disappearing.

So I would work under the assumption that you are not getting the job, and continue interviewing elsewhere, or continue working where you are right now. On the other hand, if you haven't got a new job when they call back in two months time, your chances of getting the position will be improved, because some of the competing candidates will have found positions elsewhere.